# Electrolysis of high resistivity liquids

Tags: electricity

Should I be worried about electrolysis effects if I'm measuring the resistivity of a very high resistivity liquid (1,1,1,2-Tetrafluoroethane) (around 10^14 ohm-cm)? I'll be attempting to use high voltages (up to 30kV) to do the measurement since I think it's a requirement and will have a small separation distance between the electrodes (around a cm). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then it is probably more electrical breakdown (arcing) that one should worry about. And maybe about pulses caused by muons and other ionizing radiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any electrolysis to occur, you need charge carriers, like ions (cations and anions). 1,1,1,2-Tetrafluoroethane is an *extremely stable chemical compound* that under no circumstances undergoes autolysis (autodissociation or the splitting up of a compound into cations and anions, as evidenced by water, acids, bases, salts etc). For that reason you shouldn't fear any electrolysis effects.

[Breakdown field strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength#Breakdown_field_strength) *may* be of greater concern at high voltages/small distances between electrodes.